# How to pause and stop SKScene without having performance issues?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

I am writing a program using Swift3 in Xcode. I am using SpriteKit and SKScene in my program. As you know, there is a predefined update function that always runs (even when the view changed) in gamescene.sks.

I know that "self.scene.view.paused = YES;" does not work for update functions that are always called.

Is there any way to pause and stop SKScene and its update function?

Comment: What are you talking about?  View.paused stops the view from calling spritekits update methods,  scene.pause stops all children, but update still happens

Comment: @Knight0fDragon you are always making comment to my questions, but again always you are saying nothing. I am asking that how I can pause/stop update function. In other words, I am saying how I can make update still not happen. I know that "self.scene.view.paused = YES;" does not stop update and I am asking how to do that man.

Comment: you did not understand my comment then,  "self.scene.view.paused = YES;" DOES pause the update, which is why I am confused

Answer (score 1):

Apples DemoBot is always a good project to check out.

The best way to pause your game is to create a world node and pause that node instead of pausing the skView.

```
let worldNode = SKNode()
```

add it in didMoveToView in your GameScene.

```
addChild(worldNode)
```

Than add all the nodes (or SKActions) that you want paused to the worldNode

```
worldNode.addChild(SOMENODE)
worldNode.addChild(SOMENODE2)
```

Than in your pause method you say

```
worldNode.isPaused = true
physicsWorld.speed = 0
```

and in your resume method you say

```
worldNode.isPaused = false
physicsWorld.speed = 1
```

Than for the update method you can exit early if the worlNode is paused

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

     guard !worldNode.isPaused else { return }

     // rest of your code
}
```

Hope this helps.